# LIM data access from R

Tags: r

How can one access [**LIM**](http://www.lim.com/) from [**R**](http://www.r-project.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whit Armstrong wrote a package for that:

```
Package: RLIM
Title: R interface to LIM database
Version: 0.7.0
Maintainer: Whit Armstrong <armstrong.whit@gmail.com>
Author: Whit Armstrong <armstrong.whit@gmail.com>
Depends: fts
Description: LIM interface
License: GPL-3
```

You can find the sources [here](http://github.com/armstrtw/rlim), and it depends on his [fts](http://github.com/armstrtw/fts) package.